# PHP: search comma separated string in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a mysql query which simply looks into mysql to find `LIKE` strings and displays the result.

Within the same mysql query, I have 2 `LIKE`.

*1 is always a single string and the other one can be single and sometimes multiple strings separated by commas.*

when I use my code, I get no results at all even though I have all the fields in the mysql database and I also have all the search strings in the columns.

This is my code:

```
$area = 'London';
$res = 'santandar, HSBC, RBS, ';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM banks WHERE location LIKE '%$area%' AND name LIKE '%$res'";
```

I also tried it with preg_match and it didn't return anything:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM banks WHERE location LIKE '%$area%' AND name LIKE '".preg_match($res)."'";
```

If I remove the second LIKE and my code looks like below, it works just fine:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM banks WHERE location LIKE '%$area%'";
```

So the issue starts when I try to search using a comma separated string.

Could someone please advise on this issue?

EDIT:

The PHP varibles are POSTS so they can be anything in each post.

they are like so:

```
$area = $_POST['area'];
$res = $_POST['res'];
```

Comment: looks like you want a LIKE IN / CONTAINS statement, e.g. name LIKE IN ('%santandar%', '%HSBC%', '%RBS%') .

Not possible in mysql AFAIK.

Comment: Show us some sample records that contain the data you think should match.

Comment: are you creating $res code level. if so can you try `in` something like `.. name in (".$res.")";`

Comment: @Iftikhar, the php variables $res and $area are both PHP POSTS. i just used the strings to show you guys what they will look like once they are posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to blow this out into separate `LIKE`s with an `OR`, such as:

```
...WHERE location LIKE '%{$area}' AND (name LIKE '%{$name1}%' OR name LIKE '%{$name2}' OR ...)
```

You could write this fairly simply with some PHP logic:

```
function build_like_or( $values, $field_name ) {
    // Create an array from the comma-separated values
    $names = explode( ',', $values );
    // Trim all the elements to remove whitespaces
    $names = array_map( 'trim', $names );
    // Remove empty elements
    $names = array_filter( $names );
    $where = array();
    // Loop over each, placing the "LIKE" clause into an array
    foreach( (array)$names AS $name ) {
        $where[] = "{$field_name} LIKE '%{$name}%'";
    }

    // Glue up the LIKE clauses.
    $where = '(' . implode(' OR ', $where) . ')';
    // Results will be something like:
    // $where = "(name LIKE '%santadar%' OR name LIKE '%HSBC%')"
    return $where;
}
```

Usage:

```
$area = 'London';
$res = 'santandar, HSBC, RBS, ';
$name_where = build_like_or( $res, 'name');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM banks WHERE location LIKE '%$area%' AND {$name_where}";
// echo $sql outputs "SELECT * FROM banks WHERE location LIKE 'London' AND (name LIKE '%santadar%' OR name LIKE '%HSBC%' OR name LIKE '%RBS%')
```

Comment: Thanks.. what is $names and where does it come from?

Comment: also, what are $values, $field_name and where are they coming from?

Comment: See the "Usage" example.  The `build_like_or` is a function that you can pass in the arguments.  The function accepts two arguments: `$values` (in your case, the `$res` string), and `$field_name` (in your case, the `$name` string).  This allows it to be called as often as you need, with as many different field(s) or field name(s) as you need.

Comment: For more information on your qustions (about `$names` and where it comes from, etc), please see this article: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_functions.htm

Comment: @Jackson - I have tested it, it works perfectly, exactly as is.  I apologize that you don't understand how functions work, but this code is exactly correct, and does exactly what you want.  **anyone who writes PHP functions** would in fact understand where $values and $field_name come from.  Did you read the article I linked to?  I don't have the space in this answer to provide a full tutorial on how functions work.

Answer (score 2):

you should use an `OR` condition:

```
 $res_array  = explode(',' $res)

 $num_elem= count($res_array)  // with this value you can build dinamically the query 

"SELECT * FROM banks WHERE location LIKE '%$area%' 
 AND ( name LIKE concat('%', $res_array[0]), 
     OR  LIKE concat('%', $res_array[1]) 
     OR  LIKE concat('%', $res_array[2]) ";
```

Comment: hmm... but that is only good if we know the strings. the strings are PHP posts... So, they could be different on each post.

Comment: I have update the answer with a suggestion .. if you recive the string by post you explode the string in an array and build the query dinamcally

Comment: Your second edit is only good if you know how many strings we gonna get in the post. as I said, we never know what we get in the post. it could be 1 or it could be multiple (no set amount/number).

Comment: I have update then answer with the suggestion for manage the string you receive and typos correct

Comment: This won't work, because in the OP you can see there's an extra comma at the end, PLUS there's space(s) around the commas, so you'll be searching for " ", as well as "HSBC ".

Comment: This wont work at all any way. because you are still using $res_array[0], $res_array[1], $res_array[2]...